# Display outlook ribbons at runtime

Tags: c#, add-in, outlook-addin

I have an AddIn with 2 ribbons.

The first ribbon1 in a separate class displays it's button on the : `Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer` toolbar.

The second which i just created `ribbon2`, is meant to display the Add-In,when the user right clicks, thus `ContextMenu`.

I did not build the first `ribbon1`, so i can't see how it's called since there is no :

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    return new Ribbon1();
}
```

Probably because of the third-party Add-In xPress i am using.

So the first ribbon runs fine without that method, but if i include the method in other to display the `Ribbon2`, only `ribbon2` is available  at runtime. Ribbon1 disappears. It occurs to me that it is an override method.

How can i run both ribbons simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

The following method belongs to VSTO and can't be used in Add-in Express based add-ins:

```
 protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject
```

You can handle the `OnRibbonBeforeLoad` event of the add-in module class where you can get the XML markup generated by Add-in Express components:

```
    private void AddinModule_OnRibbonBeforeLoad(object sender, AddinExpress.MSO.ADXRibbonBeforeLoadEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Xml);
    }
```

P.S. Do you get any UI errors?

By default, if an add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom Ribbon does not appear, or why a Ribbon appears but no controls appear. See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) for more information.